# Appending data frames that satisfy regular expressions in loop in R?

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, rbind

I asked a similar question earlier but asked it confusingly. So now I'm trying to do it in a more orderly fashion.

I'm running a loop that imports up to 6 dataframes based on 650 ID variables. I want to append these 6 dataframes for every one of the 650 cases. I import the data like this:

```
for(i in 1:650){
  try(part1 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/09July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part2 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/08July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part3 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/16July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part4 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/17July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part5 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/userTimeline/24July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
  try(part6 <-  read.csv(file = paste0("Twitter Scrapes/searchTwitter/24July/",MP.ID[i],".csv")))
```

This all works fine. If any part doesn't exist, the try-arguments makes sure that the loop continues to execute.

So, for some cases, not all 6 datasets exist. This means I can't simply have the next line read

```
combinedData <- rbind(part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6)
```

as one of these elements may not exist and therefore mean that the appended dataset can't be produced. This is why I thought it would be good to have the rbind command run for any dataframe that satisfied a regular expression requirement, i.e. partX. In this case, even if, say, part5 doesn't exist, it can simply append the existing other dataframes and then move on to the next ID in the loop.

However, I have no idea how to do this. It would be amazing if you could help me with this, and I'm really sorry for posting the confusing question earlier.

Comment: Have you tried initializing each of your data frames to `NULL` for example `part 1 <- NULL; part2 <- NULL` ...etc.  Prior to running your loop

Comment: AMAZING! that worked, thank you so much! do you want to post that as an answer and I'll give you an upvote/

Comment: Stick them in a list! Rather that `part1 <- ` use `parts[[1]] <-`, then you can `do.call(rbind, parts)` and get whatever's there. You could also make it dynamic so it's not restricted to exactly 6 parts. You'll just need `parts = list()` as the first line in your loop to re-initialize it as an empty list each time.

Answer (score 0):

I might use the `recursive` argument in `list.files` instead and use lists:

```
(lf <- list.files('~/desktop/test', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/feb/three.csv"
# [2] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/one.csv"  
# [3] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/three.csv"
# [4] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/two.csv"  
# [5] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/one.csv"  
# [6] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/two.csv"
```

you can group by ids by `grep`'ing

```
id <- c('one','two','three')
for (ii in id) {
  print(lf[grepl(ii, lf)])
  cat('\n')
}

# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/one.csv" "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/one.csv"
# 
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/two.csv" "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/two.csv"
# 
# [1] "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/feb/three.csv" "/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/three.csv"
```

so using this idea, you can use `lapply` to read them in resulting in **one** object with all the data frames

```
ll <- lapply(id, function(ii) {
  files <- lf[grepl(ii, lf)]
  setNames(lapply(files, function(x)
    read.csv(x, header = FALSE)), files)
})
setNames(ll, id)

# $one
# $one$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/one.csv`
# V1
# 1 one
# 
# $one$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/one.csv`
# V1
# 1 one
# 2 one
# 3 one
# 
# 
# $two
# $two$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/two.csv`
# V1
# 1 two
# 
# $two$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jul/two.csv`
# V1
# 1 two
# 
# 
# $three
# $three$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/feb/three.csv`
# V1
# 1 three
# 
# $three$`/Users/rawr/desktop/test/jan/three.csv`
# V1
# 1 three
```

And then `rbind` them:

```
lapply(ll, function(x) `rownames<-`(do.call('rbind', x), NULL))

# [[1]]
#    V1
# 1 one
# 2 one
# 3 one
# 4 one
# 
# [[2]]
#    V1
# 1 two
# 2 two
# 
# [[3]]
#      V1
# 1 three
# 2 three
```

or you can `rbind` them in the step before